# How is the Angular framework loaded into an application with Angular CLI?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I'm converting an existing AngularJS application to a hybrid application, to begin incrementally upgrading it to Angular 4. I want to understand how Angular 4 needs to be referenced in the existing AngularJS. In the existing AngularJS application, it's clear how the AngularJS framework is being loaded - it's simply an included script file:

```
<script src="/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

To familiarise myself with an up to date Angular version, I've created a separate 'quickstart' Angular *5* application using the Angular quickstart guide at https://angular.io/guide/quickstart, and I can run it using:

```
ng serve --open
```

When I look at the project files though, I'm not seeing where the angular framework is actually being loaded. There is no script being included anywhere in the src/index.html file for that application, it simply declares an  directive for a component (app.component.ts) that looks like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Test Angular 5 app';
}
```

Where does the import actually import from? The Angular documentation says about the index.html file that it is:

> The main HTML page that is served when someone visits your site. Most
>   of the time you'll never need to edit it. The CLI automatically adds
>   all js and css files when building your app so you never need to add
>   any  or  tags here manually.

So what is happening here? How is @angular/core actually being referenced?

Comment: Did you try ng build then look at your index.html in the build (dist) folder?

Comment: @Christian Santos's answer suggests OP didn't even bother to look at the built `index.html` file.

Comment: My intention was to explain the process that led to the creation of the `index.html` file.

Comment: Then you should have asked that. Look at `ng-build` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: Thanks Chau I didn't know about ng-build, I've been using ng serve to run up the 'independent' Angular 5 application I created. When I try ng build from inside my source folder I get the error message 'You seem to not be depending on "@angular/core", although I have @angular/core": "^5.0.0" as a dependency in my package.json. No 'dist' folder has yet been created through running ng serve, so there is no way yet for me to view a built html file - and ng serve seems able to work without requiring a static compiled html file?

Comment: Make sure you run `ng build` in the root directory, not the `src` directory. Regarding the location of the generated files, see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using Angular CLI, we have a lot of moving parts. To really understand what's happening, we should review some of the core technologies used in Angular CLI as they relate to output files and module resolution:

- TypeScript -- will transpile your TypeScript code to ES5 or ES6 (most commonly ES5). The transpiled code will use **CommonJS** modules by default if the target is ES5. If the target is ES6, then **ES6 modules** will be used.
- Webpack -- will take your transpiled TypeScript code and build a **dependency graph** of your import / exports based on the **entry points** defined in `webpack.config.js`. This dependency graph will include all of your modules and it will package these modules into 1+ **bundles**, depending on the configuration. This is the step where the `@angular/core` dependency (which lives in `node_modules/@angular/core`) is processed by Webpack and added to a bundle that can be accessed at runtime.

You can load the generated bundles into the page by including the generated files in your HTML. In the case of JS files, you load them using the `script` tag like you did with AngularJS.

Because we are using Angular CLI, there are a lot of configurations within Webpack that are set up by default, so we will have multiple generated bundles.

I just created an empty Angular CLI project and inspected the HTML to see the 5  generated bundles:

[image]

At the core of the complexity when comparing Angular project files with AngularJS files is that Angular code is transformed through multiple build steps, while AngularJS code is normally used out-of-the-box with ES5. If you were to add Webpack and TypeScript to your AngularJS build, you would see something very similar to the Angular output.

---

**Where is Webpack Configured in Angular CLI?**

Under the hood, Angular CLI uses Webpack to build your project and bundle your files.

The Angular team chose not to expose a configurable Webpack configuration file for Angular CLI, but they did add `ng eject`, which generates a `webpack.config.js` that matches the Webpack build of your project. The downside of ejecting is that you will no longer use `ng serve` to serve your project. Instead, you'll use `npm run build && npm run start` (you'll see these scripts added to your `package.json` after you eject), which will build and serve your project based on the generated `webpack.config.js` file.

This feature is essential if you need to make custom modifications to the default Webpack build.

Read more about `ng eject` [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/eject).

**Where are the generated bundles?**

If you are using `ng serve`, you won't see any of your generated files because these are being served from **memory** and not from **disk** (to speed up development when files are constantly changing), so your generated files are not located in any folder.

If you want to see your generated files, you can run `ng build`, which will create a `dist` folder with the `index.html` and associated assets/bundles.

Note that by default, all commands that build or serve your project will delete your `dist` folder unless you pass the `--no-delete-output-path` when building/serving.

Comment: Thanks Christian this is the kind of detail I was looking for! I'm confused though as to where Webpack comes in. I can't see any reference to webpack being used anywhere in my project and I can't see a 'compiled' html file anywhere after I've created the project using the angular cli and run ng serve.

Comment: Hey Chris -- see my updated answer that covers your questions. Let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: There's one more thing I'm not clear on -  I *guess* TypeScript on its own can do the module bundling, however the Angular CLI is using WebPack to do fuller bundling that can including html, image and other asset bundling to make the bundling more comprehensive? Or is there a reason that WebPack *must* be used for the module bundling?

Comment: You're right -- we could just use TypeScript and use AMD or SystemJS to handle modules (most browser versions do not natively support modules, so we have to use a module loader in the browser). But adding Webpack makes a lot of sense because it enables us to do things like code splitting, tree shaking, CSS modules, lazy module loading and more. Simply put it's the most comprehensive bundler out there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand how **imports** and **exports** work in **TypeScript**

From [TypeScript Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html)

**Exporting a declaration**

> Any declaration (such as a variable, function, class, type alias, or
>   interface) can be exported by adding the export keyword.

*Validation.ts*

```
export interface StringValidator {
    isAcceptable(s: string): boolean;
}
```

*ZipCodeValidator.ts*

```
export const numberRegexp = /^[0-9]+$/;
export class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
    isAcceptable(s: string) {
        return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
    }
}
```

**Export statements**

> Export statements are handy when exports need to be renamed for
>   consumers, so the above example can be written as:

*ZipCodeValidator.ts*

```
class ZipCodeValidator implements StringValidator {
    isAcceptable(s: string) {
        return s.length === 5 && numberRegexp.test(s);
    }
}
export { ZipCodeValidator };
export { ZipCodeValidator as mainValidator };
```

**Import**

> Importing is just about as easy as exporting from a module. Importing
>   an exported declaration is done through using one of the import forms
>   below:

**Import a single export from a module**

```
import { ZipCodeValidator } from "./ZipCodeValidator";

let myValidator = new ZipCodeValidator();
```

imports can also be renamed

```
import { ZipCodeValidator as ZCV } from "./ZipCodeValidator";
let myValidator = new ZCV();
```

**Import the entire module into a single variable, and use it to access the module exports**

```
import * as validator from "./ZipCodeValidator";
let myValidator = new validator.ZipCodeValidator();
```

Since you followed the Angular quickstart guide you must have used **npm** which is used to install your modules and dependencies.

If you read [angular.io/npm](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages)

> @angular/core: Critical runtime parts of the framework needed by every
>   application. Includes all metadata decorators, Component, Directive,
>   dependency injection, and the component lifecycle hooks.

And by default npm stores all your dependencies in **node_modules** directory.

So you are importing **Component** from *@angular/core* which lives inside **node_modules** directory.